# VBA Code- Flow Loop through range of data

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new to VBA and in need of assistance. I have built a traditional input output excel model (spreadsheet calculations in traditional excel, not VBA.) I have a series of 200,000 or so data points for which I need to pull a value for the 8 cells in a row (replace Sheet 1 cell A1 with value Sheet2 value cell B1), pull the result, and loop through the remaining 200,000 rows. Is there anyone who may be able to guide me in doing so?

I ran a macro with the following code to reflect the first row's replacement. I now need it to loop through the remaining columns:

```
Sub PermutationResults2()
'
' PermutationResults2 Macro
'

'
Sheets("Investments").Select
Range("I9").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=' Monte Carlo Data'!R[20]C[-8]"
Range("I10").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=' Monte Carlo Data'!R[19]C[-8]"
Range("I11").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=' Monte Carlo Data'!R[18]C[-8]"
Range("I12").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=' Monte Carlo Data'!R[17]C[-8]"
Range("I13").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=' Monte Carlo Data'!R[16]C[-8]"
Range("I14").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=' Monte Carlo Data'!R[15]C[-8]"
Range("I15").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=' Monte Carlo Data'!R[14]C[-8]"
Range("I16").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=' Monte Carlo Data'!R[13]C[-8]"
Range("I17").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=' Monte Carlo Data'!R[12]C[-7]"
Range("J9").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=' Monte Carlo Data'!R[20]C[-7]"
Range("J10").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=' Monte Carlo Data'!R[19]C[-7]"
Range("J11").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=' Monte Carlo Data'!R[18]C[-7]"
Range("J12").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=' Monte Carlo Data'!R[17]C[-6]"
Range("J13").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=' Monte Carlo Data'!R[16]C[-6]"
Range("J14").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=' Monte Carlo Data'!R[15]C[-6]"
Range("J15").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=' Monte Carlo Data'!R[14]C[-6]"
Range("J16").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=' Monte Carlo Data'!R[13]C[-6]"
Range("J17").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=' Monte Carlo Data'!R[12]C[-5]"
Range("J18").Select
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share some sample data?

Comment: Side note: I hardly recommend to read and follow [VBA Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices) especially the part about how to avoid using Select and ActiveCell.

Comment: @progsnob I just added an image with the data. Essentially if you could imagine taking this data and replacing separate cell values with these listed (there is about 200,000 rows). Then on a separate sheet, this returns an ROE. And I need the cell replacement to then continue to the next row, pull the ROE and loop again. Does this make sense?

Comment: @RachelAnn it looks like you are reversing the order of the data as well, is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Let's get you started

```
   Sub Demo
     Dim r as range
     dim t  as range
     Set r = Sheets("Investments").Range("I9")  'point to your start cell
     set t = sheets(" Monte Carlo Data").range("I9")  'pointer to your destination
      Do Until r = ""  'keep going till you find a blank cell
          t = r  'copy value in r into t
          set r = r.offset(1,0) 'move pointer down one
          set t = t.offset(1,0)  'ditto for the other pointer
      Loop
 end sub
```

Now play with that till it does what you want to do